# Apache2 Named Based and IP Based (SSL) with Apache2 and sites-enabled Scheme

Tags: linux, debian, apache-2.2

With one IP, how can I set up two domains where:

1. *.foo.com is name based for port 80 only.
2. *.bar.com catches all requests both 80 and 443 that are made to the IP, or *.bar.com

Can I do this using the sites-enabled scheme?

Update to make this more clear, I think I may have overstated my requirements:

```
If http.header.host == ^.*?.foo.com:
   then serve('/var/www/foo');
else if tcp.port == 443:
   serve.ssl('/var/www/bar');
else 
   serve('/var/www/bar')
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, all that happens with sites-enabled is that Apache reads everything in that file in as part of the config. You can have multiple virtual hosts in a file. You can have all the virtual hosts in apache2.conf and have nothing in sites-enabled. You could put all your vhosts in conf.d. The only difference with sites-enabled is that the a2ensite command knows to symlink files to sites-available.

As for your question:

You can have:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443
<Virtualhost *:80>
   ServerName www.foo.com
   ServerAlias *.foo.com
   ...
</VirtualHost>

<Virtualhost *:80>
   ServerName www.bar.com
   ServerAlias *.bar.com
   ...
</VirtualHost>

<Virtualhost *:443>
   ServerName www.bar.com
   ServerAlias *.bar.com
   SSLEngine on
   ...
</VirtualHost>

<Virtualhost 12.34.56.78:80>
   ServerName www.bar.com
   ServerAlias *.bar.com
   ...
</VirtualHost>
<Virtualhost 12.34.56.78:443>
   ServerName www.bar.com
   ServerAlias *.bar.com
   SSLEngine on
   ...
</VirtualHost>
```

You will need to have a wildcard SSL certificate for *.bar.com, and you'll only be able to use one SSL certificate on the server, rather than one per IP address.

ServerName doesn't take wildcards, but ServerAlias does, which is why I've used both.

Comment: Thanks, does order matter if I put them in separate files in sites enabled?

Comment: Only which one is first. The first one is the one that's used when a hostname doesn't match ServerName or ServerAlias.

Comment: So are they just loaded in alphabetic order? I have tried your config, but when I try putting foo.com into my hosts file, I am still getting directed to the DocumentRoot of www.bar.com even with the flat file .. :-/

Comment: You can specify a DocumentRoot for each VirtualHost

Comment: sebthebert: I did, the problem is that I'm not getting the right one ...

Comment: SSL sites should not be a name virtual host, it its a non-sense as "Host: " HTTP1.1 header is not available at this level (it is inside the SSL tunnel)

So, make a simple catch-all Virtual Host for the 443 port

Comment: Another point to underline is that it would be a better choice to set ServerName as "foo.com" and not "www.foo.com".

This way you can handle the "pure domain" host too, leaving the canonical "www" being handled by the wildcard in the ServerAlias directive

Comment: It seems 
<Virtualhost 12.34.56.78:80> Will take precedence over <Virtualhost *:80> even if the former is listed first ...

Comment: Dammit, I was using the ServerName twice in one of them instead of ServerAlias ... sigh. ..

Comment: It's entirely possible to use named virtual hosts with SSL as long as you're using a wildcard certificate that covers all the hosts you you want to host.